# What's up this week?

Tags: discussion

This is a cool thing someone is trying to start at reddit:
http://www.reddit.com/r/gaming/comments/ixo7u/this_week_in_gaming_july_17_23/

I don't think SE format is better at that particular weekly update type thing (reddit isn't really either) but I think it's neat and thought I'd mention it in case anyone thought of a way for it to be relevant to this community (or ways we could do something related).

Comment: This reminds me of the Sunday Papers section that Rock Paper Shotgun does every week. [Here's an example](http://www.rockpapershotgun.com/2011/04/17/the-sunday-papers-166/). Maybe we could do this for our community blog too!

Answer (score 1):

I think the only place that something like that would work is on the blog, as Mana suggested. If we are properly vigilant, questions about a specific week in gaming should be closed as "too localized" or "not a real question" on sight ... as you point out, those types of questions simply don't work on the site.

Comment: Note that [Joystiq already does this](http://www.joystiq.com/2011/07/25/now-playing-july-25-31-2011/).